# Undefined offset 0, but still gives me correct result

Tags: php

```
$options = array('health', 'strength', 'agility', 'stamina', 'defence');

$total = array();

foreach ($options as $value)
{
    foreach ($objects as $object)
    {
        $total[$value] += $object->$value;
    }
}

var_dump($total);
```

I have some objects in an array called `$objects`. It's giving the data to the `$total` as it should do.

But by some reason it's whining about some undefined offset.

```
 Notice: Undefined index: health in C:\wamp\www\objbattle\index.php on line 32
```

Line 32 is: `$total[$value] += $object->$value;`

Why!? And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Because `$total['health']` doesn't exist on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you try to increment an uninitialized value. Try initalize them first.

```
$total = array('health' => 0, 'strength' => 0, 'agility' => 0, 'stamina' => 0, 'defence' => 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect because you are trying to increment an un-initialized value...

try assigning on the first round instead, like this:

```
$total[$value] = $object->$value;
```

or more simply, initializing the array values...

```
$total = array();
$total['health'] = 0;
etc...
```

or do it like @josmith suggests in his answer

Comment: He is looping through $objects I assume he try to populate all the values in to some sort of array thus he can't just assign it, as it would be overridden the next iteration.

Comment: he can assign in the loop on the first iteration by testing which iteration the loop is in, or outside the loop he can assign after declaring the variables

Comment: You edited your post, the same second I downvoted it. Now however your post doesn't deserve a downvote, but I can't upvote it back.

Comment: I actually voted for your answer, I think it is the most succinct.

Comment: It tells my vote is locked. You must edit your answer in order for me to upvote it back :)

Answer (score 0):

The key 'health' doesn't exist of the first loop through the for each. As a result you will get the notice.

You can do:

```
$total[$value] = 0;
```

Right above the second foreach.

Or, you could do it the lazy way and suppress the NOTICE:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be encouraged to suppress the notice. It's not good practice :)

Comment: I agree, but it is the default setting for error reporting on PHP4 and PHP5

Answer (score 0):

Why!?
I think because Sets which PHP errors are reported.